# Magento 2.1.1 two add to cart button in product view page

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1, addtocart

I want to have two add to cart in product view page.

So from somewhere I've found the following code

```
<?php 
    $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_product), ['product' => $_product->getEntityId()])
?>
<button class="action tocart primary"
        data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postData; ?>'
        type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
</button>
```

Where `$_product` is my product. well this code is working fine for the simple products but not working for configurable products where I've to choose options(like size,color etc.)..

Even if I select all those attributes the default add to cart button is working fine but that button created by code is giving me error

> You need to choose options for your item.

So anyidea how can I solve this issue for configurable products??